# Check correctness of data using only publicly known variables and a server response

Tags: data-privacy, checksum, remote-data-checking

A smart contract (a publicly known program) needs to check if the data D is correct (belongs to some fixed set). It is by definition correct if our trusted server checks it and decides it's correct.

To check it, the contract receives a hash H from a trusted server. The server knows secret S. It should be impossible to infer S from H.

So we have a publicly known function f(D, H, S) with unknown to the public argument S.

Is it possible for the smart contract to check whether the data is correct without using any unknown to public variables (including S)?

It seems for me that it is impossible: the contract could check it only comparing f(D, H, S) to some fixed value (or set of values), but we can't because we don't know S. Right?

Or is there some cunning way to check it without revealing S?

The smart contract can't ask the server. Smart contract can be called by a hacked with arbitrary D and H. Hacker should be unable to convince the contract that it is called with correct data.

The server cannot write to the blockchain (otherwise it would be trivial: the server would write a pair of D and its correctness boolean value, the contract then would just check it).

---

It seems that the above question is equivalent to the following formal problem:

Having natural number D and number H dependent on D, is it possible to check correctness of D (it belonging to some set) by checking if g(D, H) = 0 for some publicly known function g? (H is allowed to be forged by a hacker.)

Comment: Why are you using a hash to determine whether D is an element of a set? You are looking up hash in list of hashes of correct values rather than looking up data in list of correct data?

Comment: @AdrianSelf Because I cannot query my server from the smart contract due to technical restrictions. The data set is practically infinite, so I could not look up the hash "in the list". The issue is how to produce the hash and how determine if the hash is correct.